# Can I blackbox an external script when debugging javascript in Webstorm?

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I am running a debug session in Webstorm on a page that uses ckeditor (loaded via remote script). When the editor loads the debugger stops somewhere in the external (minified) script despite there not being a breakpoint in there.  Does anyone know if I can tell Webstorm to ignore this file?

Comment: debugger shouldn't normally stop in scripts that don't have breakpoints. Are exception breakpoints enabled? Please check Breakpoints dialog (Run/View breakpoints). If no line/exceptions breakpoints are set, then it's a bug. I'd suggest creating a support ticket, providing a sample project that shows up the issue

Comment: No line/exception breakpoints are set. If I navigate to the page that uses the external script then the debugger doesn't stop but reloading that same page it stops in the same file every time. Thanks @lena